# Poincaré map under small pertubations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-theory

Let $\gamma$ be a periodic orbit of a vector field $X$. Through a point $x_{0} \in \gamma$ we consider a section $\Sigma$ transversal to the field $X$ and V a small neighbourhood which contains $x_{0}$.

Consider $P_{X}: V \subset \Sigma \rightarrow \Sigma$ the Poincaré map, which to each point $x \in V$ associates $P(x)$, the first point where the orbit of $x$ returns to intersect $\Sigma$.

If $Y$ is a vector field sufficiently near to vector field $X$, my questions are:

1) Is $\Sigma$ transversal to $Y$?

2) Is true that the orbit of $Y$ through each point of $V$ still returns to intersect $\Sigma$?

In the first question if $\Sigma$ were not transversal to $Y$ (in a point p), then $Y(p) \in T_{p}\Sigma$, since $Y$ is close to the $X$ we have $X(p) \in T_{p}\Sigma$, which contradicts transversality. 
(Is my argument correct? Can I take the topology over $T\Sigma$?)

Is the second question related to the structural stability? I don't know if the statement is true.

I'm self studying Dynamical Systems, so I'm having some trouble to make some stuffs precise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Regarding the first question: the flow of a $C^1$ perturbed field is still transversal, although perhaps on a proper subset of the original section. A proof can be the following: if you have a Riemannian metric on the manifold, transversality means that the field on $\Sigma$ is not orthogonal to the normal, which is an open property in the $C^1$ topology. The second question has nothing to do with structural stability, either. I think that the best approach would be through the flow box theorem: the orbit of the perturbed flow gets close to the section, so it will be pushed across it.

Comment: @user539887 Thanks for helping me with this. Where I can find about the flow box theorem? I know the Tubular flow theorem, is the same thing?

Comment: I think that's the same. Other names: straightening out theorem, rectification theorem. You can find it, e.g., in Chicone [Ordinary Differential Equations with Applications](https://www.amazon.com/Ordinary-Differential-Equations-Applications-Mathematics/dp/0387307699).